# Gradle sync failed: Exception thrown while executing model rule: BaseComponentModelPlugin.Rules#createVariantData(ModelMap

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I was running android application very well then i updated Android Studio to **3.0** and Gradle version to latest **4.1**. After Synch the project i got following build error

```
    e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: Exception thrown while executing model rule:
BaseComponentModelPlugin.Rules#createVariantData(ModelMap<AndroidBinaryInternal>, ModelMap<AndroidComponentSpec>, TaskManager) > afterEach()
```

I will be thankful for this quick favour.

Comment: Any luck with the fix for this? Facing the same issue.

Comment: Same problem here upgrading to com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.11.0. Can't do much with it erroring like this.

Answer (score 5):

Temporary solution, which worked for me, was to change the following things:

1. In top level .gradle file - change version of experimental plugin to 0.9.3:

   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.9.3'
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
   }
2. Change Gradle plugin version from 4.1 to 3.3 in gradle-wrapper.properties

   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip

It works with android studio 3.0

Comment: I find that these versions work in Android Studio 3.5 and 3.5.1... to produce _unsigned_ APKs, but that if I try to build a codesigned APK with them, I get "The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle". So now I'm thinking I need to find a version of Android Studio that will codesign using 3.3. Have you been able to codesign APKs using these Gradle versions on Android Studio 3.0?

Comment: I've just encounter this problem once and back then I solved as I described.

Comment: Ah, thanks for replying! I finally (just tonight) managed to codesign APKs using these same setting and Android Studio 3.0... but only 32-bit versions. You don't happen to remember if you could codesign 64-bit APKs, or what you did to get that to work, do you? I have a question on the topic languishing for attention at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58565006/how-can-i-codesign-an-android-apk-using-the-gradle-experimental-plugin